# ¿Qué diferencia hay entre "descontento con" y "descontento sobre"?

Tags: preposiciones

¿Hay alguna diferencia entre "descontento con" y "descontento sobre"?

Ejemplos:

- La población está descontenta con/sobre el alto costo de vida.
- Hay un largo descontento con/sobre el alto costo de vida.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La diferencia es que "con" combina con los adjetivos "contento" y "descontento", mientras que "sobre" no es idiomático. Del mismo modo que decimos:

> ✔ Estoy contento con la rebaja en el precio.

y NO:

> ✘ Estoy contento sobre la rebaja en el precio.

lo idiomático es decir:

> ✔ La población está descontenta con el alto costo de vida.

y NO:

> ✘ La población está descontenta sobre el alto costo de vida.

Con el sustantivo "descontento", la historia es diferente, y -- además de "con" -- se podría utilizar "sobre", "acerca de", "en torno a", "respecto de", etc.

- Hay un gran descontento con / sobre el alto costo de vida. (aunque, en lugar de "sobre", son preferibles las locuciones preposicionales arriba mencionadas.)

En caso de que puedan coexistir ambas preposiciones con el sustantivo "descontento", "con" puede introducir a personas o asuntos, mientras que "sobre" sólo puede introducir asuntos:

- Hay un gran descontento con el alto costo de vida.
- Hay un gran descontento sobre el alto costo de vida.
- Hay un gran descontento con el ministro de economía.

pero NO:

> ✘ Hay un gran descontento sobre el ministro de economía.

Answer (score 1):

Se puede usar siempre **con** y algunas veces **sobre**, unida a [descontento](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Cj9XSzZ)

La regla de uso que observo es que

- la preposición "**con**" que [indica la causa](https://diccionario.reverso.net/espanol-definiciones/con) (*en razón de*, o *en relación a*) , se aplica versatilmente para *contento* tanto —se lo use como adjetivo o sustantivo.
- Mientras que con "[**sobre**](https://diccionario.reverso.net/espanol-definiciones/sobre)" (*acerca de*) funciona sólo cuando *descontento* es un sustantivo (y no un adjetivo)

Con *descontento* como sustantivo, ambos usos funcionan

> Hablamos sobre la molestia del usuario por su **descontento con** el producto)
>
> El usuario transmitió su **descontento sobre** la calidad del producto
>
> (...) Esta huelga demostró que el consenso sobre la privatización aún no se ha logrado en Corea y que, por el contrario, el descontento sobre el plan de privatización aplicado ha aumentado (extraído [de este uso](http://www.socialwatch.org/es/node/10313))

Pero, en tanto descontento usado cual adjetivo, **sobre** no aplica (ya que sería como decir "insatisfecho *sobre*", y no *con*, como corresponde)

> *Estoy muy **descontento con** la calidad de este producto*
>
> "Estoy muy **descontento sobre** la calidad de este producto (MAL)